# upgrade angular2 rc6 to rc7

Tags: npm, npm-install

How can I upgrade my angular2 project from rc6 to rc7 ?
After hours of googling, I haven't find a solution.

This command line:

```
npm update angular2
```

Say that there are no update available.

Comment: just update your package.json and npm install

Comment: In package.json change 2.0.0-rc.6 to 2.0.0-rc.7 and run npm install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: The official 2.0.0 Release is there! :)

To face your problem, just change your package.json.

From this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.x",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.x",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.x",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.x",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.x",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.x",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.x",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.x",
    ...
  },
```

To this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1", // !! UPDATE THESE ENTRIES TOO !!
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12", // !! UPDATE THESE ENTRIES TOO !!
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1", // !! UPDATE THESE ENTRIES TOO !!
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23" // !! UPDATE THESE ENTRIES TOO !!
  },
```

and run in the same directory `npm i` or the long command: `npm install`